# Find system equations for the system shown in the figure and F-V analogous circuit

Tags: control-engineering

[image]

Can't seem to understand how the 2 bodies would interact with each other. For most other problems I use the Nodal method by using the displacements as nodes and then connecting all other elements to those and the writing the equations
So it would be really helpful if someone can show how to write the system equations for this

Comment: Hi @Shubh. Welcome to Engineering. What is D1 and D2?

Comment: You would probably have to replace D1 and D2 with dash pots. Dash pot D1 would have one emd connected to M1 and other to M2. This is only a guess since you have not mentioned what Di are.